# ArcGIS / .Net - Load pyramids in thread

Tags: arcobjects, .net, image-pyramids, multithreading

I need to display a large raster with ArcGIS. To do so, I'm using pyramids, and it is working, but they can be long to build. So I would like to build the pyramids in a separate thread. When doing so, the layer is added in the TOC, but not on the map.

Here is a sample code :

```
private class Worker {

    private delegate void RasterLoadedCallback(IRasterDataset rasterDataset);

    public void DoWork() {

        // Set the workspace and file names :
        string workspacePath = "C:\\Path\\To\\My\\Folder";
        string fileName = "filename.tif";

        // Open a workspace :
        IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = new RasterWorkspaceFactory();
        IRasterWorkspace rasterWorkspace = (IRasterWorkspace)workspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(workspacePath, 0);

        // Open a file in the workspace :
        IRasterDataset rasterDataset = rasterWorkspace.OpenRasterDataset(fileName);

        // Create the pyramids :
        IRasterPyramid rasterPyramids = (IRasterPyramid)rasterDataset;
        rasterPyramids.Create();

        // Run on the main thread :
        RasterLoadedCallback callback = AddRasterToMap;
        Dispatcher.FromThread(mainThread).Invoke(callback, new object[] { rasterDataset });
    }

    private static void AddRasterToMap(IRasterDataset rasterDataset) {

        // Create a raster layer from a raster dataset :
        IRasterLayer rasterLayer = new RasterLayer();
        rasterLayer.CreateFromDataset(rasterDataset);

        // Add it to a map if the layer is valid.
        if (rasterLayer != null) {

            IMap map = MyAxMapControl.ActiveView.FocusMap;
            map.AddLayer((ILayer)rasterLayer);
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what could the problem be ?

Comment: This is a very specific technical question about ArcObjects, I would recommend you ask this on Geonet.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this forum, it may help me in the future, but I found an answer (see my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution : re-open the raster in the main thread when the pyramids creation is done, instead of passing the dataset as a parameter.

So the my code is :

```
private class Worker {

    private delegate void RasterLoadedCallback();

    public void DoWork() {

        // Set the workspace and file names :
        string workspacePath = "C:\\Path\\To\\My\\Folder";
        string fileName = "filename.tif";

        // Open a workspace :
        IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = new RasterWorkspaceFactory();
        IRasterWorkspace rasterWorkspace = (IRasterWorkspace)workspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(workspacePath, 0);

        // Open a file in the workspace :
        IRasterDataset rasterDataset = rasterWorkspace.OpenRasterDataset(fileName);

        // Create the pyramids :
        IRasterPyramid rasterPyramids = (IRasterPyramid)rasterDataset;
        rasterPyramids.Create();

        // Run on the main thread :
        RasterLoadedCallback callback = AddRasterToMap;
        Dispatcher.FromThread(mainThread).Invoke(callback, new object[] { });
    }

    private static void AddRasterToMap() {

        // Open a workspace :
        IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = new RasterWorkspaceFactory();
        IRasterWorkspace rasterWorkspace = (IRasterWorkspace)workspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(workspacePath, 0);

        // Open a file in the workspace :
        IRasterDataset rasterDataset = rasterWorkspace.OpenRasterDataset(fileName);

        // Create a raster layer from a raster dataset :
        IRasterLayer rasterLayer = new RasterLayer();
        rasterLayer.CreateFromDataset(rasterDataset);

        //rasterLayer.PyramidsPresent = true

        // Add it to a map if the layer is valid.
        if (rasterLayer != null) {

            IMap map = MyAxMapControl.ActiveView.FocusMap;
            map.AddLayer((ILayer)rasterLayer);
        }
    }
}
```